Node.js ECONNRESET: Error: socket hang up when making HTTP request
I'm encountering a "socket hang up" error when trying to make an HTTP request in my Node.js application. Here's the error message I'm receiving:
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:628:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:499:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:532:15)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}


function makeRequestWithRetry(options, maxRetries = 3) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let attempts = 0;
    
    function attempt() {
      attempts++;
      requestHTTP(options, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err && attempts < maxRetries) {
          console.log(`Attempt ${attempts} failed. Retrying...`);
          setTimeout(attempt, 1000 * attempts); // Exponential backoff
        } else if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve({res, body});
        }
      });
    }
    
    attempt();
  });
}

async function cobrancaBoleto(request, callback) {
  console.log(" ~ cobrancaBoleto ~ cobrancaBoleto:");

  var valor = request.payload.valor;
  var vencimento = request.payload.vencimento;
  var descricao = request.payload.descricao;
  var identificador_externo = randomUUID();
  var instrucao = request.payload.instrucao;
  var pagador = request.payload.pagador;
  var tipo_multa = request.payload.tipo_multa;
  var multa = request.payload.multa;
  var aplicar_multa = request.payload.aplicar_multa;
  var aplicar_juros = request.payload.aplicar_juros;
  var tipo_juros = request.payload.tipo_juros;
  var juros = request.payload.juros;
  var aplicar_desconto = request.payload.aplicar_desconto;
  var tipo_desconto = request.payload.tipo_desconto;
  var data_limite_desconto = request.payload.data_limite_desconto;
  var desconto = request.payload.desconto;
  var dias_expirar = request.payload.dias_expirar;
  var cliente = await request.payload.cliente;
  console.log("125  ~ cobrancaBoleto ~ cliente:", cliente)

  var tipo_transacao = "boletoCashin";
  console.log("passou aqui");
  var token = request.auth.token;

  console.log(" ~ cobrancaBoleto ~ identificador_externo:", identificador_externo);

  sessaoDAO.getSessaoColaborador(token, async function (colaborador) {
    if (colaborador != null) {
      console.log("passou aqui bora");
      console.log(" ~ colaborador:", colaborador);
      var form = {
        valor: valor,
        vencimento: vencimento,
        tipo_transacao: tipo_transacao,
        identificador_externo: identificador_externo,
        descricao: descricao,
        instrucao: instrucao,
        pagador: pagador,
        aplicar_multa: aplicar_multa,
        tipo_multa: tipo_multa,
        multa: multa,
        aplicar_juros: aplicar_juros,
        tipo_juros: tipo_juros,
        juros: juros,
        aplicar_desconto: aplicar_desconto,
        tipo_desconto: tipo_desconto,
        data_limite_desconto: data_limite_desconto,
        desconto: desconto,
        dias_expirar: dias_expirar,
        cliente: cliente,
      };

      var formData = JSON.stringify(form);
      console.log(" ~ formData:", formData)
      var contentLength = formData.length;
      console.log('bora que bora -----------------------------')

      AUTH.getToken(colaborador[0].id_unidade, async function (token) {
        console.log("250 TOKEN CHEGOU AQUI do boleto ------------------:", token);
        if (token != null) {
          console.log(token);
          try {
            const options = {
              headers: {
                "Content-Length": contentLength,
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                Authorization: token,
                // 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                // 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=1000'
              },
              url: AUTH.CRIARCOBRACABOLETO,
              body: formData,
              method: "POST",
              // timeout: 30000 // 30 segundos de timeout
            };

            const { res, body } = await makeRequestWithRetry(options);

            console.log("entrou aqui legal");
            try {
              var resposta_obj = JSON.parse(body);
              console.log(" ~ body:", body);
              console.log("271 RESPOSTA DO OBJETO BOLETO", resposta_obj);
              callback(resposta_obj);
            } catch (parseErr) {
              console.error("Erro ao parsear a resposta:", parseErr);
              callback({
                code: 500,
                mensagem: "Erro ao processar a resposta",
              });
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.error("Erro na solicitação:", err);
            callback({ code: 500, mensagem: "Erro na solicitação" });
          }
        } else {
          var data = {
            code: 400,
            mensagem: "Opção não habilitada para uso.",
          };
          callback(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      var data = {
        code: 401,
        mensagem: "Token Inválido",
      };
      callback(data);
    }
  });
}

This error occurs when I'm trying to make a POST request to an external API. The connection seems to be reset unexpectedly during the request.
I've already tried the following:
Implementing a retry mechanism with exponential backoff
Increasing the request timeout
Adding 'Connection: Keep-Alive' headers
Verifying that the request payload is correct
Despite these attempts, the error persists. The request sometimes fails on the first attempt, and sometimes on subsequent retry attempts.
My environment:
Node.js version: [v14.17.6 (npm v6.14.15)]
Operating System: [Debian GNU/Linux 11]
HTTP client library: [var requestHTTP = require("request");]
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest additional troubleshooting steps? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
